# Ada - how to define task parameters

Tags: ada

I am new in Ada.

My problem is:

Create in programming language ADA:

There are 6 lakes. Each of lakes has:

- 4 swans with number of feathers: 100, 200, 300, 400 and
- 7 geese with number of feathers: 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100.

There are 10 hunters. Each hunter plans to hunt 3 swans and 5 geese. 
Each hunter hunts in as many different lakes as possible (second bird from the same lake hunter hunts only after he has tried successfully or unsuccessfully to hunt in other lakes). Each time a hunter chooses to hunt a bird with most feathers from the available birds of the type he is looking for.

2 hunters first look for swans (and search for geese only after they have hunt required number of swans or when no more swans is in lakes), and 8 hunters first look for geese.
When hunter has obtained required number of swans and geese, he says the total number of feathers he has hunted. The hunter, who has not obtained the required number of feathers, says how many swans and how many geese he is missing.

Instructions: Describe both hunters and lakes as TASK arrays in ADA; if hunter x wants to hunt a swan from lake y, hunter calls the lake from which either he receives the number of feathers received during synchronization or he receives rejection if there is no any swan or geese in lake. The disclosure of the output data must be made by printing them at the standard output.

All hunters must complete their job in parallel. All TASKs in the program and the program itself must quit work. It is forbidden to use time control to ensure that the program stops working.

Information on the activities of the hunters, the birds that they hunt, and remaining of swans or geese in each lake it is forbidden to keep in global variables or in any other structure outside the hunts or lakes. Information is exchanged between the main application and the taskbooks only on the basis of message exchange; tasks does not use the access to variables defined outside them.

First I want to understand how to define the rules. My solution at this time is this:

```
 with Ada.Text_IO;
 use Ada.Text_IO;

  procedure Birds is

  type Hunter (Swans, Geese);
  type Swans(100,200,300,400) of Integer;
  type Geese(500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100) of Integer;

Hunter_Number_Of_Birds : INTEGER := 0;
  Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake : INTEGER := 66;
                      -- The main program adds and deletes birds to hunters and from the lakes.

  task Hunter is
     entry Hunts_Swans(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds swans to hunter
     entry Hunts_Geese(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds geese to hunter
  end Hunter;

  task Lake is
     entry Swans(dates: in Integer);  -- This deletes swans from lake
     entry Geese(dates: in Integer);  -- This deletes geese from lake
  end Lake;


  task body Hunter is

  begin
  for Index in 1..8 loop

     select
        when   Hunter_Number_Of_Birds =>8
        accept Hunts_Swans do
             Hunter_Number_Of_Birds :=   Hunter_Number_Of_Birds + 1;

           Put_line("Hunter adds swans, count =");
           Put(Hunter_Number_Of_Birds);
           New_Line;
        end Hunts_Swans;
     or
        when Hunter_Number_Of_Birds =>8
        accept Hunts_Geese do
            Hunter_Number_Of_Birds :=   Hunter_Number_Of_Birds + 1;
           Put_Line("Hunter adds geese, count =");
           Put(Hunter_Number_Of_Birds);
        end Hunts_Geese;
     end select;
  end loop;
 end Hunter;

 task body Lake is
  begin
     for Index in 1..5 loop

     select
        when  Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake =>66
        accept Swans do
            Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake :=  Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake - 1;

           Put_line("Hunter hunt swans, remaining number of swans in the lake =");
           Put(Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake);
           New_Line;
        end Swans;
     or
        when Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake =>66
        accept Geese do
           Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake:=  Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake - 1;
         Put_line("Hunter hunt geese, remaining number of geese in the lake =");
           Put(Lake_Number_Of_birds_In_Lake);
        end Geese;
     end select;
  end loop;
 end Lake;
```

I have no idea how can I define:

- Number of hunters and lakes;
- number of feathers of each beards;
- 2 hunters first look for swans and 8 hunters first look for geese;
- count the feathers

Comment: You must also consider how to tell two hunters to only hunt swans and 8 hunters to only hunt geese. The problem description refers to some required number of feathers for each hunter. You must consider how to tell each hunter how many feathers to acquire. The problem will work best if the hunters randomly select lakes to hunt so that they are not all trying to hunt the same lakes at the same time.

Comment: It is possible to declare task types. Then you can declare arrays of such tasks.

Comment: The name of the language is Ada, not ADA (it's not an acronym).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Number of hunters and lakes;
> ```
>
> As mentioned in the comments, change your task declarations to task types:

```ada
  task type Hunter is
     entry Hunts_Swans(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds swans to hunter
     entry Hunts_Geese(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds geese to hunter
  end Hunter;

  task type Lake is
     entry Swans(dates: in Integer);  -- This deletes swans from lake
     entry Geese(dates: in Integer);  -- This deletes geese from lake
  end Lake;
```

Then you just need to declare them as arrays:

```ada
type Hunter_Array is array(1..10) of Hunter;
type Lake_Array is array(1..6) of Lake;

Hunters : Hunter_Array;
Lakes   : Lake_Array;
```

> ```
> number of feathers of each beards;
> ```
>
> Here I would create a birds package and use Ada.Containers.Bounded_Vectors:

```ada
package Birds is
    type Bird is (Swan,Goose);
    type Feather_Count is new Natural;
end Birds;

use type Birds.Feather_Count;
package Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Bounded_Vectors
        (Index_Type   => Positive,
         Element_Type => Birds.Feather_Count);

use type Vectors.Vector;

Swans : aliased Vectors.Vector 
    := Vectors.To_Vector(100,1) & 200 & 300 & 400;

Geese : aliased Vectors.Vector
    := Vectors.To_Vector(500,1) & 600 & 700 & 800 & 900 & 1000 & 1100;
```

Using the vector allows you to keep track of the number of birds left in the lake (you can call Swans.Length for example) and when hunted you can get the feathers by calling

```ada
Feathers := Swans.Last_Element;
Swans.Delete_Last;  -- Takes it out of the vector
```

Essentially using the vector as a stack.

> ```
> 2 hunters first look for swans and 8 hunters first look for geese;
> ```

For this I would change your Hunter task definition to:

```ada
  task type Hunter(Prefers : Birds.Bird := Birds.Swan) is
     entry Hunts_Swans(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds swans to hunter
     entry Hunts_Geese(dates: in Integer);  -- This adds geese to hunter
  end Hunter;
```

and add a constructing function for it:

```ada
  function Swan_Hunter return Hunter is
  begin
      return Result : Hunter(Birds.Swan);
  end Swan_Hunter;

  function Goose_Hunter return Hunter is
  begin
      return Result : Hunter(Birds.Goose);
  end Goose_Hunter;
```

Then you can change your Hunter array declaration to:

```ada
  Hunters : Hunter_Array := 
      (1 => Swan_Hunter, 
       2 => Swan_Hunter, 
       others => Goose_Hunter);
```

After that you just need to add the logic to keep track of if they are currently hunting geese or swan and compare it to their preference to know how to proceed.

> ```
> count the feathers
> ```

When you hunt from a lake, have the entry also return the number of feathers.  Then you can just add them together everytime it is successful and have the hunter keep a running total for himself/herself.